# Checking values of 2 columns from a command output in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script that attempts to see if SELinux is enabled using the sestatus command. I am currently using:

```
sestatus | awk '$1=="SELinux status:" && $2=="enabled" {print}'
```

This does not return anything when sestatus shows:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

How do I check and return a true value of a row when column 1 of the sestatus command output is "SELinux status:" and column 2 is "enabled"?

Comment: `sestatus | awk '$1=="SELinux" && $2=="status:" && $3=="enabled"'` -- why do you think you have 2-fields?? (`awk` splits on *whitespace* by default)

Comment: `sestatus | grep -q 'SELinux status:\s*enabled' && echo true || echo false`

Comment: That is the better way to go.

Comment: It is better to use an if statement for that imo, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3